# Reference local json object in controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is probably trivial thing to do, but I am so new to angularJs that I am unable to find right answer for this.

I have one object that I want to move from controller, where it was originally define into some object file, and then I want to import that object back into controller so I can use it's values.

[image]

So basically UTCTimeZones.js is object container that has this value inside:

```
export default {
    timeZones: [{ value: "Dateline Summer Time", name: "UTC-12", offset: "+1200" }, { value: "UTC-11", name: "UTC-11", offset: "+1100" },
                { value: "Aleutian Standard Time", name: "UTC-10", offset: "+1000" }, { value: "Marquesas Standard Time", name: "UTC-9:30", offset: "+0930" },
                { value: "Alaskan Standard Time", name: "UTC-9", offset: "+0900" }, { value: "Pacific Standard Time", name: "UTC-8", offset: "+0800" },
                { value: "US Mountain Standard Time", name: "UTC-7", offset: "+0700" }, { value: "Central America Standard Time", name: "UTC-6", offset: "+0600" },
                { value: "Haiti Standard Time", name: "UTC-5", offset: "+0500" }, { value: "Pacific S.A. Standard Time", name: "UTC-4", offset: "+0400" },
                { value: "Newfoundland Standard Time", name: "UTC-3:30", offset: "+0330" }, { value: "E. South America Standard Time", name: "UTC-3", offset: "+0300" },
                { value: "UTC-02", name: "UTC-2", offset: "+0200" }, { value: "Azores Standard Time", name: "UTC-1", offset: "+0100" },
                { value: "UTC", name: "UTC", offset: "+0000" }, { value: "Central Europe Standard Time", name: "UTC+1", offset: "-0100" },
                { value: "GTB Standard Time", name: "UTC+2", offset: "-0200" }, { value: "Belarus Standard Time", name: "UTC+3", offset: "-0300" },
                { value: "Iran Standard Time", name: "UTC+3:30", offset: "-0330" }, { value: "Arabian Standard Time", name: "UTC+4", offset: "-0400" },
                { value: "Afghanistan Standard Time", name: "UTC:4:30", offset: "-0430" }, { value: "West Asia Standard Time", name: "UTC+5", offset: "-0500" },
                { value: "India Standard Time", name: "UTC+5:30", offset: "-0530" }, { value: "Nepal Standard Time", name: "UTC+5:45", offset: "-0545" },
                { value: "Central Asia Standard Time", name: "UTC+6", offset: "-0600" }, { value: "Myanmar Standard Time", name: "UTC+6:30", offset: "-0630" },
                { value: "SE Asia Standard Time", name: "UTC+7", offset: "-0700" }, { value: "W. Australia Standard Time", name: "UTC+8", offset: "-0800" },
                { value: "North Korea Standard Time", name: "UTC+8:30", offset: "-0830" }, { value: "Aus Central W. Standard Time", name: "UTC+8:45", offset: "-0845" },
                { value: "Tokyo Standard Time", name: "UTC+9", offset: "-0900" }, { value: "AUS Central Standard Time", name: "UTC+9:30", offset: "-0930" },
                { value: "E. Australia Standard Time", name: "UTC+10", offset: "-1000" }, { value: "Lord Howe Standard Time", name: "UTC+10:30", offset: "-1030" },
                { value: "Russia Time Zone 10", name: "UTC+11", offset: "-1100" }, { value: "New Zealand Standard Time", name: "UTC+12", offset: "-1200" },
                { value: "Chatham Islands Standard Time", name: "UTC+12:45", offset: "-1245" }, { value: "Tonga Standard Time", name: "UTC+13", offset: "-1300" },
                { value: "Line Islands Standard Time", name: "UTC+14", offset: "-1400" }]
};
```

All of the timezones, with some additional data inside timeZones object.
How can I import this file and access timeZones from some other files, for example from NewTestSessionController.js that looks like this:

```
import toastr from "toastr";

    class NewTestSessionController {
        constructor($rootScope, $scope, $state, resources, NewTestSessionService) {
            this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.$state = $state;
            this.resources = resources;
            this.NewTestSessionService = NewTestSessionService;

            this.clientDateTimeZone = null;
            this.sessionDate = {
                opened: false,
                dateOptions: {
                    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    startingDay: 1
                },
                format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
            };

            this.viewData = {
                events: [],
                locations: [],
                sessionStarTimeIntervals: this.generateTimeIntervalArray(15),
                timeZones: //reference json UTCTimeZones object here, ...
```

What is the best way to do it? Do I import it like I did with toastr, or maybe inject whole object in constructor like I did with `NewTestSessionService`?

This service is defined in index.js:

```
import NewTestSessionController from "./NewTestSessionController";
import AddNewPersonDirective from "./AddNewPersonDirective";
import NewTestSessionService from "./NewTestSessionService";
import UTCTimeZones from "./UTCTimeZones";

export default angular.module("examino.hrTesting.newTestSession", ["ui.router", "examino.constants"])
    .config(function($stateProvider, config) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("hrTesting.newTestSession", {
                url: "/new-test-session",
                controller: "NewTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: config.getTemplateLocation("new-test-session.html"),
                controllerAs: "newTestSessionCtrl"
            });
    })
    .controller("NewTestSessionController", NewTestSessionController)
    .service("NewTestSessionService", NewTestSessionService)
    .directive("xmAddNewPerson", AddNewPersonDirective)
    .name;
```

Here I have `.controller`, `.service`, `.directive` for registering different things. What would then I use for object?

What would you suggest as best scenario when getting local object?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use service to pass values. 
"Angular services are:

Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory."

In controller you can pass dependency and then use that value from service.

Please read
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches here:

## Angular constants

You can define an [Angular constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) if the object isn't going to change at all. I'm making the assumption that since these are time zones, you're unlikely to change them.

```
    angular.module("examino.hrTesting.newTestSession", ["ui.router", "examino.constants"])
.config(function($stateProvider, config) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("hrTesting.newTestSession", {
            url: "/new-test-session",
            controller: "NewTestSessionController",
            templateUrl: config.getTemplateLocation("new-test-session.html"),
            controllerAs: "newTestSessionCtrl"
        });
})
.controller("NewTestSessionController", NewTestSessionController)
.service("NewTestSessionService", NewTestSessionService)
.directive("xmAddNewPerson", AddNewPersonDirective)
.constant("TimeZones", {
    timeZones: [
        { 
          value: "Dateline Summer Time", 
          name: "UTC-12", offset: "+1200"
        }
        // and other time zones
   ]
)
.name;
```

Once the constant is defined, you just reference it through an argument in your controller function

```
function NewTestSessionController($http, TimeZones) {
    // do something with TimeZones here
}
```

The advantage of using constants is that they can be injected into other controllers and services, and clear errors if the code tries to modify the value of the constant

## Asynchronous calls

This is harder but more flexible. If this is a config file that can be updated at any time, you can use `$http` to pull in the config file asynchronously from your backend. Your controller would use a `$http.get` call to get the time zone object. This frees you up to make changes independent of the code, and also to call third-party APIs to provide the same data in the future. The drawback is that you now have to wrap all subsequent functionality into the promise result once you get the config file. As your application scales, and if your config files need to change flexibly , this might be the better approach for you.